# React native ref property: Function vs React.createRef()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used to create refs like this:

```
class MyComponent extends PureComponent<Props> {  
  constructor (props: Props) {
    super(props)
    this.panRef = null
  }
  
  panRef:PanGestureHandler | null
  listRef:ScrollView | null

  render () {
    const { children } = this.props
    return (
        <PanGestureHandler
          onGestureEvent={() => console.log('onGestureEvent')}
          ref={ref => this.panRef = ref}
          simultaneousHandlers={this.listRef}
        >
          <NativeViewGestureHandler
            ref={ref => this.listRef = ref}
            simultaneousHandlers={this.panRef}
          >
            <ScrollView>
              {children}
            </ScrollView>
          </NativeViewGestureHandler>
        </PanGestureHandler>
    )
  }
}
```

It was working fine for react-navigation, all kinds of inputs interactions etc. Now I had to work with `react-native-gesture-handler`. And this way of assigning refs wasn't working for it. Here is what does work:

```
class MyComponent extends PureComponent<Props> {  
  panRef = React.createRef()
  listRef = React.createRef()
  render () {
    const { children } = this.props
    return (
        <PanGestureHandler
          onGestureEvent={() => console.log('onGestureEvent')}
          ref={this.panRef}
          simultaneousHandlers={this.listRef}
        >
          <NativeViewGestureHandler
            ref={this.listRef}
            simultaneousHandlers={this.panRef}
          >
            <ScrollView>
              {children}
            </ScrollView>
          </NativeViewGestureHandler>
        </PanGestureHandler>
    )
  }
}
```

Looks like the `NativeViewGestureHandler` wasn't assigning refs correctly with the former way of assigning refs. But it does the job with the `React.createRef()`. Here are the components involved in my example: [`NativeViewGestureHandler`](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/master/NativeViewGestureHandler.js) and its [`createNativeWrapper`](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/master/createNativeWrapper.js).

Could someone please explain the difference between the former and the latter way of assigning refs?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a ref can be done by a ref object (object with `.current` key) or a callback.

The difference between the two, is that `ref={ref => this.panRef = ref}` (the first example) is a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

> Instead of passing a ref attribute created by `createRef()`, you pass a function. The function receives the React component instance or HTML DOM element as its argument, which can be stored and accessed elsewhere.

---

Behind the scenes, assigning a reference is a callback:

```
ref => {...}
```

So (in the second example) using React API for creating a ref `React.createRef`/`useRef`, will generate:

```
myRef = React.createRef();
<>
  <div ref={this.myRef} />
  // Same
  <div ref={(ref) => (this.myRef.current = ref)} />
</>;
```

- [`React.createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref)

Comment: why there is more than one way to do the same thing? Is this considered to be a poor design?

Comment: No. There are use cases for both, while `createRef` is more common. Check the link of **callback ref**.

Comment: With hooks, you only will able to assign a ref with `useRef`. Such callback available only on classes due to the class property.